# Conditional probability, with multiple events $P(A \ \& \ BT)$ =?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I saw a picture saying something along the lines of "Alice is sick, Bob is healthy. If Alice doesn't wear a mask, and Bob does, there is a 70% probability of transmission. If Alice wears a mask and Bob doesn't, there's a 5% chance of transmission. If Alice and Bob wear masks, there is a 1.5% chance of transmission"

This got me to thinking, "what if both don't wear masks?"

So the known stuff is `P(T|~A&B) = 70%`, `P(T|A&~B) = 5%`, and `P(T|A&B) = 1.5%`. And to find P(T|~A&~B), I'd use bayes theorem. But I can't figure out how to apply it. I think we assume Alice and Bob wearing masks is independent, so P(A&B) = P(A)*P(B). But I don't know if I can pull that out of a "given" statement. That is to say, can we assume `P(A&B|T) = P(A|T)&P(B|T)`?

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer that.   Think of it square with four quadrants (according to who is wearing a mask and who is not).  Convince yourself that we can set the probability of transmission independently in each quadrant.

Comment: As for $A,B$ independent whether that implies that $P(A\cap B\mid T) = P(A\mid T)\times P(B\mid T)$, clearly not.  Consider the uniform distribution on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and let $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{1,3\}$ and $T=\{1,4\}$.  You'll see that these are pairwise independent events (*though not mutually independent events*).  Despite this, $P(A\cap B\mid T) = \frac{1}{2}\neq P(A\mid T)\times P(B\mid T) = \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}$